# How to declare variable name equal to filename present in a directory and variable value equal to content of file?

Tags: bash, shell

I have some files in a folder with content as a 4 digit number in each file. How can I export variable `name=filename` and its `value=filecontent` with a loop in bash?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is quite simple.

```
#!/bin/bash
dir="."
for file in "$dir"/*
do
  [[ -f "$file" ]] || continue
  var="${file##*/}"
  if
    printf -v "$var" "$(<"$file")" 2>/dev/null
  then
    export "$var"
  else
    echo "Invalid filename: $file"
  fi
done
```

Not all filenames are valid variable names.  You would need to either make 100% sure all files you could ever use your script with have names that are valid variable names, or (preferably) perform some kind of test or error handling.  The script above will detect a failed assignment, but will not do anything to clever aside from complaining.

Some explanations...

The loop body is skipped if the file is not a regular file (i.e. directory, special files are skipped).

The code uses the `-v` option of `printf`, which causes `printf` to assign a value whose name is provided instead of printing to stdout.  This is safer than, say, improperly using `eval`, which would open up code injection possibilities, especially considering you are using filenames which the script cannot control.

The `"$(<"$file")"` statement is a command substitution that outputs the content of the file, like a redirection that produces a string rather than a stream.

Finally, please note that if you want to `export` the variables in preparation for other things your script will do, you are fine.  However, if you want to export these variables to the shell that calls the script, you will need to execute the script with `.` (or `source`), because a child process can never export (or make any kind of assignment) to the variables of its parent.  Sourcing causes the shell to read the commands from the stated file without starting a child process.

Comment: Would be worth mentioning exporting from a script can never affect the parent shell. If that is what OP is aiming at. (sourcing the result in the parent is a possibility)

Comment: Using this code throws error as Invalid filename: c:/mydir/a where say "a" is a filename

Comment: @Harsh  Should be fixed now.

Comment: still the contents of the file say "a" is not stored in created variable "a". echo $var gives a, i need to store content of file a in a

Comment: Are your executing your script with `source` or `.` as explained in the answer?  If you run it with `bash` or with `./script_name`, the assigned variables will not be available once the script terminate as they will be lost when the child process ends.